# Identify this insect - genus, species

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Please help identify this insect - genus, species and anything interesting about it.

Note, this is [posted separately due to comments in this other thread](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/64042/can-you-identify-these-insects?noredirect=1#comment115250_64042).

[image]

[image]I'm

Comment: Please add the location where it was found. That helps with ID

Comment: Locations are not available :( - there's very little data associated with each one other than additional photos

Answer (score 2):

This one is most probably a longhorn beetle ([Cerambycidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longhorn_beetle)). The long elytrae (protective forewings) and the long curved antennae are quite typical.

Yours looks a bit like this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosalia_longicorn
It is probably a different species, though.

Comment: do you have further advice or methodology insight on identifying the species

Comment: @ina The way that is taught at school is to use a determination key, but in practice, identification often starts with a familiarity with the group of interest. I would advise to browse an insect identification guide, where species are grouped in families, and get an intuitive feeling of what insects in a given family look like, alongside with general description that the guide gives. Then, to get more precise ID, one has to find a determination key that covers the group of interest. Often, these documents are specific for a region. Some technical notions are often needed.